# Checking data passed from Arduino into Processing

Tags: arduino, processing, rfid

As part of a project my group has to program an Arduino to get a signal from an RFID, and pass data into Processing depending on said signal. For example, when a tag is sensed by the Arduino, String data would be passed into Processing and handled there.

We have the Arduino part working but Processing is throwing up errors. In our project we must wait for user input at certain points.

```c
public int readRFID()
{
  int tagNumber = 0;

  //Has to be contained in try/catch because of errors with null
  try
  {


  if ( myPort.available() > 0) {  // If data is available,    
      val = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');
    }    // read it and store it in val

  //Convert val into integer and set to tagNumber
  tagNumber = Integer.parseInt(val);
  }

  //An error occurs if val is null, which is the case every time unless it actually gets data
  catch(Exception e)
  {
    tagNumber = 0;
  }

  return tagNumber;

}
```

At the end, tagNumber should be returned as either 0 or a positive value (when a tag is present and there is a number to be read in). In the method that calls this method we have this:

```c
//RFID SCANNING GOES HERE
int tag = 0;
while (tag == 0)
{
  //When RFID reads as null, this method should return 0 until a tag
  //is read in
  tag = readRFID();
}

//userChoice is set to the number read in -1 because tags are numbered 1, 2, 3, 4
//but userChoice will refer to an index in an array that starts at 0
userChoice = tag - 1;
```

We are not sure why this code isn't working - all we're sure of is that the method has to be continuously called until a tag is present. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Processing is throwing up errors" and "code isn't working". What exact errors are you getting? *How* is it not working?

Comment: Since you are polling the RFID, I think you might need to give some time for read. May be you can try putting some delay after readRFID().

Comment: Where are the errors exactly?